# Search for function call in php in order to generate a translation file

Tags: php, grep, pattern-matching

I am developing a php website that needs to be multilingual.
For this reason, I implemented a translation function which has the following header:

```
function t($string, $replace_pairs = array(), $language = NULL)
```

Basically, this function is called like this in multiples files of my project:

```
echo '<p>' . t('Hello world!') . '</p>';
$hello_String = t("Hello @name!", array('@name'=>$username));
```

I haven't generated the translation strings yet and I would like to generate multiple translation file automatically (one for each language).

What I am looking for is a bash program (or a single command, using grep for example) that would look for every call to this t() function and generate a php file with the following structure:

```
<?php
/* Translation file "fr.php" */
$strings['fr']['Hello world!'] = '';
$strings['fr']['Hello @name!'] = '';
```

Has anyone ever encountered this situation and could help me with this ?

Thank you very much.

Kind regards,

Matthieu

Comment: I really think this could be done with grep but I don't know much about regexp nor have time now to learn about them. Could some one provide me with a command to print the file, location and function call to this t() function ? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: I think that it is a "multilingual template system" problem, not a "translation file" only. See my solution.

Comment: This might be a little too late but I also came accross this problem. Not entirely the same because I used gettext, but implemented a custom function ___ (three underscore) instead of the usual _ or \_\_.

If you actually went the gettext route, you can scan using xgettext with the keywordspec option (-k) and specifying your custom function, in my case -k___ , like so:

    `find . -iname "*.php" | xargs xgettext --from-code=UTF-8 -o /tmp/messages.pot -L PHP -k___`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No need to reinvent the wheel

Drupal uses the same t() function for its localization and the [potx](http://drupal.org/project/potx) module is your friend.

If you don't already have, or want to install, a drupal instance you can look at the [potx.inc](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/potx/blob/7.x-3.x/potx.inc) file and reuse it in your script.

Here is the complete [API documentation](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/potx/potx.module/6.3) for the translation template extractor.

Comment: I inspired myself of drupal's t() function but didnt know about this ptox file. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you're not exactly the first to come across this. :)

You can use the venerable gettext system for this, you don't need to invent your own functions. Then you'd get to use [`xgettext`](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=xgettext), which is a command line utility to extract strings using the [`_()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php).

If you want to roll your own system for whatever reason, your best bet is to write a PHP script which uses [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/token_get_all) to tokenize the source, then go through the tokens and look for `T_FUNCTION`s with the value `t`.

Comment: these tools seem to be nice but gettext() doesn't provide substitution capabilities, which implies that i should edit all my calls to my t() function to t(gettext($string), $substitution_array). This is not what i am looking for. Could i use xgettex in order to find all the calls to my t() function ?

Comment: You would traditionally substitute values using something like `sprintf(_('Hi, %s!'), $name)`. I don't know if xgettext works on custom function names as well, might be worth looking into.

Comment: I don't like the sprintf alternative because it implies to preserve the order of the arguments, which may differ from a language to another. what my t() function actually does is a strtr(). Anyway, I don't want to rewrite my entire code using strtr(_("Hello @name"), array(...)). I may end up using gettex but i would do that inside my t() function which still requires me to find all the calls to this function in my code.

Comment: You would probably always need syntax along the lines of `func('String %var', $var)`; doing something like `func(_('String %var'), $var)` is not that much more complicated. You can decide what `func` should be doing exactly. It can be `strtr`, `sprintf` or anything else. BTW, `sprintf` allows reordering parameters perfectly fine using `%1$s %2$s` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Try this script http://pastie.org/4568713

Usage:

```
php script.php ./proj-directory lang1 lang2 lang3
```

This creates `lang1.php`, `lang2.php`, `lang3.php` files in `./lang` directory

Comment: Valiant effort I commend you. Some issues and suggestions:

* the output folder is actually `./langs`
* you are assuming that all files being considered have the `.php` extension this might be limiting.
* unfortunately removing whitespace around all the ( brackets will effectively modify the comparison strings that contain a ( as well rendering them undetectable.
* Consider using [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) in your process_dir function which will reduce the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You need two functions:

1- scan directories for php files. like [this](http://lixlpixel.org/recursive_function/php/recursive_directory_scan/)

2- match your t function, grep string and generate the language file. like

```
  function genLang($file) {
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    preg_match(...);
    foreach(...){
        echo(...);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii framework also uses same functionality,
see their MessageCommand class 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/cli/commands/MessageCommand.php#L125

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a (very simple) "template system", but there are two instances of templating in your problem.

1. Transform "`Hello $X!`" into "`Hello Jonh!`" or "`Hello Maria!`", setting $X. (PHP do this for you in string declarations).
2. Select the adequate template: "`Hello $X!`" for english, "`¡Hola $X!`" for spanish.

The item 1 is the more simple, but the algorithm order is 2,1 (item 2 them item 1). 
For this simple task you not need a regular expression (to reinvent the "string with place-holder" of PHP).

### Illustrating

For item 1, the simplest way is to declare a specialized function to say "Hello",

```
// for any PHP version.
function template1($name) { return "<p>Hello $name!</p>";}
print template1("Maria");
```

For item 2 you need a generalization, that PHP do also for you, by a closure,

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); // only for remember UTF8.
// for PHP 5.3+. Use 
function generalTemplate1($K) {
    // $K was a literal constant, now is a customized content.
    return function($name) use ($K) {return "<p>$K $name!</p>"; };
}
// Configuring template1 (T1) for each language: 
$T1_en = generalTemplate1('Hello'); // english template
$T1_es = generalTemplate1('¡Hola'); // spanish template 
// using the T1 multilingual
print $T1_en('Jonh');  // Hello Jonh!
print $T1_es('Maria'); // ¡Hola Maria!
```

For more templates, use generalTemplate2(), generalTemplate3(), etc.; `$T2_en`, `$T2_es`, `$T2_fr`, `$T3_en`, `$T3_es`, etc.

### Solution

Now, for pratical use, you like to use arrays... Well, there are a datastructure problem, 
and more 1 level of generalization. The cost is variable-name parser for place-holders. I used simple regular expression with preg_replace_callback().

```php
function expandMultilangTemplate($T,$K,$lang,$X) {
// string $T is a template, a HTML structure with $K and $X placeholders. 
// array  $K is a specific language constants for the template.
// array  $lang is the language, a standard 2-letter code. "en", "fr", etc.
// array  $X is a set of name-value (compatible with $T placeholders).
// Parsing steps:
$T = str_replace('{#K}',$K[$lang],$T);  // STEP-1: expand K into T with lang.
// STEP-2: expand X into T 
global $_expMultTpl_X;  // need to be global for old PHP versions
$_expMultTpl_X = $X;   
$T = preg_replace_callback(
        '/@([a-z]+)/',
        create_function(
                '$m',
                'global $_expMultTpl_X; 
                 return array_key_exists($m[1],$_expMultTpl_X)? 
                     $_expMultTpl_X[$m[1]]: 
                     "";
                 '
        ),
        $T
    );
    return $T;
}
// CONFIGURING YOUR TEMPLATE AND LANGUAGES:
$T = "<p>{#K} @name@surname!</p>";
$K = array('en'=>'Hello','es'=>'¡Hola');
// take care with things like "!", that is generic, and "¡" that is not.

// USING! 
print expandMultilangTemplate(
        $T, $K, 'en', array('name'=>'Jonh', 'surname'=>' Smith')    );
print expandMultilangTemplate($T, $K, 'es', array('name'=>'Maria'));
```

I tested this script with PHP5, but it runs with older (PHP 4.0.7+).

About "multilingual files": if your translations are into files, you can use somthing like

```php
$K = getTranslation('translationFile.txt');
function getTranslation($file,$sep='|') {
  $K = array();
  foreach (file($file) as $line) {
      list($lang,$words) = explode($sep,$line);
      $K[$lang]=$words;
  }
}
```

and a file as

```
en|Hello 
es|¡Hola
```

### Simplest with PHP 5.3

If you using PHP 5.3+, there are a simple and elegant way to express this "simplest multilingual template system",

```php
function expandMultilangTemplate($T,$K,$lang,$X) {
    $T = str_replace('{#K}',$K[$lang],$T);
    $T = preg_replace_callback(
            '/@([a-z]+)/',
            function($m,$X=NULL) use ($X) {
                    return array_key_exists($m[1],$X)? $X[$m[1]]: '';
            },
            $T
     );
     return $T;
}
```

Comment: intresting but a little complicated and would require me to rewrite too much code.

Comment: Hello! Sorry about my english, my blalblabla was to be didactic for you and the public... But  about "complicated", I need to be empathic: it is the SIMPLEST WAY to obtain your function t(), is not?  PS: see the PHP 5.3 version, can be expressed with two lines (!).